# Change slider input values when clicking checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

I have three sliders with the labels year, length, count. I want to add a "see all" checkbox that when clicked, will change the slider inputs to the min and max of each slider respectively.

This is the code that I've tried, I'm not sure how I would change all three sliders and also if I'm doing it right in the first place?

```
observeEvent(input$checkbox==TRUE,
  updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = "years", min = 1979, max = 2015))
```

Also I'm not sure how to handle when the checkbox is un-clicked. What would be the best was to use a checkbox to update three sliders?

Comment: What behavior do you want when the checkbox is unclicked?

Comment: I guess to go back to the user inputted slider values. Or would a button be best?

Comment: Also what do you mean by setting the slider input to the min and max? Is it a "range slider" ? A "regular slider" has only one value.

Comment: Sorry yes there are three range sliders with a min and a max associated with each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app below sets the values of the range slider to the maximal range when the user marks the checkbox. And when the user unmarks the checkbox, the values of the range slider are set to their previous values. There's no difficulty to generalize to three sliders, just repeat the same code.

```
library(shiny)

slider1_min <- 0
slider1_max <- 50
slider1_init <- c(20,30)

ui <- fluidPage(

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("slider1",
                     "Range:",
                     min = slider1_min,
                     max = slider1_max,
                     value = slider1_init),
         checkboxInput("checkbox", "Set to full range")
      ),

      mainPanel()
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  slider1_values <- reactiveVal(slider1_init)

  observe({
    if(input$checkbox){
      slider1_values(isolate(input$slider1))
      updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", value=c(slider1_min, slider1_max))
    }else{
      updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", value=slider1_values())
    }
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I'm getting object 'slider1_init' not found when trying to initiate this code? Is it because I have separate ui.r and server.r files?

Comment: @user9568744 Yes. Put `slider1_min`, `slider1_max` and `slider1_init` in the file `global.R`.